# How can I migrate new versions after having executed a repair using flyway?

Tags: sql, database-migration, flyway

I executed a repair using flyway and deleted the file that caused the error.

Since I have executed the repair, it's not possible to migrate any other files anymore, although there is only one version present in the flyway info, which is just the flyway-baseline itself.

With the command flyway migrate, it says that the schema is up to date, so there is no migration necessary, although I provided textfiles in the sub-folder "sql".

It worked properly before I had executed the repair command...

Hope someone can help!

Cheers,

Yasmin

Comment: If you have run the repair command on a given database, it's going to reset things back to whatever the last build was. If it's the baseline, then, yeah, there's no more to deploy. If you're saying you've added more versions and it's not seeing that... I'm a little confused.